# How to properly override ILog log methods

Tags: c#, log4net, extension-methods, structuremap

How may I properly override ILog methods?
I want to override, for example, the method Debug, to do something before calling original method from a log4net.ILog interface.

So basically I want to achieve something like this:

```
public void Debug(string msg, Exception exc) => _log.Debug(DoSomething(msg), exc);
```

I have tried adding some extension methods to Debug/Info/Warn/Error/Fatal methods from a log4net.ILog interface and also adding some patterns to Resharper to mark plain usages of log4net.ILog methods to use this one from my Extension class.

```
public static void DebugWith(this ILog log, string msg, Exception> exc) => log.Debug(DoSomething(msg), exc)
```

But when it goes to replace all occurrences of a standard ILog method in a project I would rather configure it somehow in registry to Use methods from my custom ILog implementation, because thanks to than I could change only a couple of files instead of hundreds of them and I wouldn't belong on resharper warning annotations.

My registration looks right now like this:

In project 1:

```
For<ILog>().Use(x => LoggerManager.GetLogger("AppLogger"));
```

In project 2:

```
For<ILog>().Use(x => LoggerManager.GetLogger("AnotherLogger"));
```

Or maybe extension method is "the best" solution for log4net.ILog?

Comment: You cannot override any interface method, you have to implement an interface

Comment: Bit broad for a full answer, but we've written our own log4net wrapper that we call `GetLogger` on - it returns our own logging object that wraps an internal `ILog` that came from `LogManager.GetLogger`.

Comment: Consider using the .NET Debug class instead.  Register your own TraceListener, it can do whatever it wants before logging the message.

Comment: @JamesThorpe I think about this, but I wonder if there is some "better" approach?